# Regex gives different results for two similar cases

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string:

> Message 1 [V.Variable1] Message 2 [F.Field1] Message 3

Why does it work well in ex1 and doesn't in ex2?

```
var ex1 = Regex.Matches(message, @"\[F\.(?<name>.+)\]"); 
// the result `{[F.Field1]}` .. as expected


var ex2 = Regex.Matches(message, @"\[V\.(?<name>.+)\]");
// the result `{[V.Variable1] Message 2 [F.Field1]}` .. not as expected
```

When I'm trying to get the value of the group `name`, it gives the expected result in ex1 which is `Field1` but it returns nothing in ex2

Any idea?

Comment: Define "works well" and "doesn't". It is not clear what you expect the results to be.

Comment: When I'm trying to get the value of the group `name`, it gives the expected result in ex1 which is `Field1` but it returns nothing in ex2

Comment: Please edit your question and update with this information, instead of in a comment, where others might neglect to read it.

Comment: @Oded: Thanks, It's already done.

Comment: One more question - do you understand _why_ the result of `ex2` is what it is?

Comment: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/Greedy.html

Comment: Does regex give different results for similar messages or does the same message have different results for similar regexes?

Comment: @Oded: I think here's the problem. it doesn't stop matching at the first close bracket - which is `[V.Variable1]` - and I have not clue why that!

Comment: @Homam Check Gabi's answer and possibly read some tutorial

Comment: @Homam - quite right. The `+` operator is _greedy_. Read the link I posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make the `.+` lazy: `\[V\.(?<name>.+?)\]"` (note the question mark). The second case doesn't work because the `+` sign is greedy by default, and it will match as much as it can, in your case to the second closing square bracket from the second group.